# Redux Router Uncaught TypeError: createHistory is not a function

Tags: reactjs, history, redux-router

### Redux Router Version ^2.1.2

react-router version:  `"react-router": "^3.0.0"`,
history version: `"history": "^4.3.0"`,

### Steps to reproduce

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { reduxReactRouter, routerStateReducer, ReduxRouter } from 'redux-router';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createHistory } from 'history';

import rootReducer from './core/rootReducer';
import routes from './core/routes';

import * as axios from './utils/axios.js';

import { AUTH_USER } from './authentication/types';

const store = compose(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk),
    reduxReactRouter({ routes, createHistory })
)(createStore)(rootReducer);

const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

if (token) {
    store.dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ReduxRouter>

            {routes}

        </ReduxRouter>
    </Provider>
    , document.querySelector('.main')
);
```

It return an error `index.js:34416 Uncaught TypeError: createHistory is not a function(…)`

Any solution?

---

After changing `import { createHistory } from 'history';` to `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';`

The error become `Uncaught TypeError: history.getCurrentLocation is not a function`

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I don't know why it got downvoted, I've got exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by specifying version 3 of history in my package.json

```
"history": "^3.0.0",
```

react-router 3.0.0 specifies history 3.0.0 as a dependancy, but for some reason it isn't added to node_modules. But adding it explicitly to your own package.json fixed the problem for me.

I don't think react-router 3.0.0 is yet compatible with history v4. I'm not sure why npm is not observing the dependancy in react-router v3.0.0 package.json

Comment: The history package wasn't included with react-router-redux by default; for those who need to manually install: https://www.npmjs.com/package/history.